# How to refresh listview in fragment that is filled with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, refresh, android-arrayadapter, using

I got data from json response and showed it in `listView`. When I delete an item in `listView`, it is deleted successfully but `listView` doesn't refresh.

I am using an `ArrayAdapter` instead of a `BaseAdapter`.
CustomList.java

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {

    ImageButton imgdelete;
    private String[] clientid;
    private String[] mobile;
    private String[] grand;
    private String[] billid;
    View listViewItem;
    TextView textViewname;


    private Activity context;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] clientid, String[] mobile, String[] grand, String[] billid) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_listview, clientid);
        this.context = context;
        this.clientid = clientid;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.grand = grand;
        this.billid = billid;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null, true);
        textViewname = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.viewClientMobile);
        TextView textViewmobile = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.viewClientName);
        TextView textViewgrand = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.viewCompnayName);
         TextView textViewbillid = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.viewCompanyEmail);
        ImageButton imgedit = (ImageButton)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imgeditbtn);
       imgdelete = (ImageButton)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imgdeletebtn);
        textViewname.setText(clientid[position]);
        textViewmobile.setText(mobile[position]);
        textViewgrand.setText(grand[position]);
        textViewbillid.setText(billid[position]);

        imgdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete
                                DeleteClient_api();



                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();


                notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
        });

        return listViewItem;

    }
    protected void DeleteClient_api() {
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://befoodie.co/billingsystem/client_api.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                       // Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // final String session = ActivityLogin.MostSecureRandom.nextSessionId();
                params.put("Action", "RemoveClient");
               params.put("ClientID",textViewname.getText().toString());

                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);



    }
}
```

ViewAllClient.java

```
public class ViewAllClient extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;


    //create Array of product Details

    public ViewAllClient() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_all_client, container, false);


        //   listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listviewclient);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listviewclient);
       View_api();
               return rootView;
    }
    protected  void View_api(){
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://befoodie.co/billingsystem/client_api.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                     showJSON(response);   //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // final String session = ActivityLogin.MostSecureRandom.nextSessionId();
                params.put("Action", "ViewClients");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);



    }

    protected  void showJSON(String json){
        ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
        pj.parseJSON();

        final CustomList cl = new CustomList(getActivity(), ParseJSON.CLIENTID,ParseJSON.mobile,ParseJSON.grand, ParseJSON.billid);
        listView.setAdapter(cl);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            }
        });


    }

}
```

ParseJSON.java

```
public class ParseJSON  {


    public static String[] CLIENTID;
    public static String[] mobile;
    public static String[] grand;
    public static String[] billid;



    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "ClientDetails";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "ClientID";
    public static final String KEY_MOBILE = "ClientName";
    public static final String KEY_GRAND = "EmailID";
    public static final String KEY_BILL = "StartingCommunicationDate";



    private JSONArray users = null;

    private String json;

    public ParseJSON(String json){
        this.json = json;
    }

    protected void parseJSON(){


        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

            CLIENTID = new String[users.length()];
            mobile = new String[users.length()];
            grand = new String[users.length()];
            billid = new String[users.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
                CLIENTID[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ID);
                mobile[i] = jo.getString(KEY_MOBILE);
                grand[i] = jo.getString(KEY_GRAND);
                billid[i] = jo.getString(KEY_BILL);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, may I suggest using RecyclerView instead of ListView. Second, you can notify your adapter of any change, just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after the change is done.

Answer (score 0):

Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter object once you've modified the data in that adapter. ;

Note : For an `ArrayAdapter`, `notifyDataSetChanged` only works if you use the `add()`, `insert()`, `remove()`, and `clear()` on the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(context, ListDataHeader, ListDataChild, data);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Dipu First you have to delete the item from the local jsonresponse(which is populating your list).After that you have to notify the adapter that the data has been changed.If you deleted from inside the adapter simply write `notifyDataSetChanged();` after deleting the item.
If you are deleting from the class then you have to simply write

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
    // in ViewAllClient fragment

    public void delete(int position){
      adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);//-- only update the required row
   // notifyDataSetChanged for full listview
```

}

```
// in adapter
ViewAllClient  viewAllClient =new ViewAllClient();
viewAllClient .delete(position);
```

Comment: try adapter.notifydatasetchanged there in fragment class